# pass vertical scroll event from uibutton to tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I placed a uibutton inside of a tablecell.  When i try to scroll up and down through the table, the table does not scroll if i place my finger on the button and scroll from there.  How do I pass the scroll event up the responder chain so that the tableview can handle the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

This is very deliberate behavior in the frameworks. UIScrollView explicitly avoids taking over touch events that begin on a button. Is there any particular reason you want this to happen?

Comment: I wanted to create something like camera roll, but i don't want to use the three20 library from FB.  If the user clicked the image, a new view would be shown.  I thought using buttons would be nice because they could handle all the touch events and i wouldn't have to implement any touch handlers. is this the right approach?

Comment: Good on you for not using three20, that library is atrocious. In any case, the cleanest way of handling this is to simply not use UIButton. Any other solution is liable to be fragile and make assumptions about how UIScrollView works.

Comment: Kevin, The free highlight feature of uibutton is another reason i'm trying to make it work.